# Numpy matrix addition vs ndarrays, convenient oneliner

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

How does numpy's matrix class work? I understand it will likely be removed in the future, so I am trying to understand how it works, so I can do the same with ndarrrays.

```
>>> x=np.matrix([[1,1,1],[2,2,2],[3,3,3]])
>>> x[:,0] + x[0,:]
matrix([[2, 2, 2],
    [3, 3, 3],
    [4, 4, 4]])
```

Seems like a row of ones got added to every row.

```
>>> x=np.matrix([[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3]])
>>> x[0,:] + x[:,0]
matrix([[2, 3, 4],
        [2, 3, 4],
        [2, 3, 4]])
```

Now it seems like a column of ones got added to every column. What it does it with the identity is even weirder,

```
>>> x=np.matrix([[1,0,0],[0,1,0],[0,0,1]])
>>> x[0,:] + x[:,0]
matrix([[2, 1, 1],
        [1, 0, 0],
        [1, 0, 0]])
```

---

EDIT:
It seems if you take a (N,1) shape matrix and add it to a (N,1) shape matrix, then of one these is replicated to form a (N,N) matrix and the other is added to every row or column of this new matrix. It seems to be a convenience restricted to vectors of the right sizes. A **nice** use case was networkx's implementation of [Floyd-Warshal](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/_modules/networkx/algorithms/shortest_paths/dense.html#floyd_warshall_numpy).

Is there an equivalently convenient one-liner for this using standard numpy ndarrays?

Comment: This concept is called [broadcasting](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/user/basics.broadcasting.html). Numpy docs do a better job of explaining that I could manage.

Comment: The only difference with `ndarray` is that `x[:,0]` will be (N,) shape instead of (N,1).  So you need to add that dimension back with `x[:,0][:,None]`.  As a general rule you should become familiar with the base `ndarray` behavior, and see the `np.matrix` class as a specialized 2d array case.  You should be as comfortable using 1d arrays as 2d ones (and 3d and nd).  Even be aware of 0d.